# Change the Title on a Google Maps Marker

Tags: google-maps-api-3, google-maps-markers

Given a google maps marker how can I change the title ?

```
var _marker = new google.maps.Marker({
  position: aPoint,
  map: mmap,
  title:"old title"
});
```

I have tried

```
_marker.setTitle("new title");
```

and

```
_marker.title = "new title";
```

but the title is still "old title"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Googling your question suggests [this](http://groups.google.com/group/google-maps-api/browse_thread/thread/cc1212a62705ec70):

> The information is not held in the marker.title property. Where it is 
>   held varies from release to release. In v2.129e it's held in 
>   marker.$.title. 
>   Also, the information is only processed when you addOverlay the marker. 
>   So in v2,129e you can write: 
>   marker.$.title = "updated title"; 
>   map.removeOverlay(marker); 
>   map.addOverlay(marker);

(original answer by [Mike Williams](http://groups.google.com/groups/profile?enc_user=6DtSGxkAAAAEcnkIFCxUBF1el-f0MFgpg4IBNxq6lnlPHWToZ1dvZg&utoken=XH49HU8AAAB50wGCDof3O6R3bVykt1Tgs-2dQD5W6RgFdusJQeUhfTyDf18CrBwjiVmBOezHmpDhaxeRLE5xmKyWpIKxEJOLphcfwIzFWAbM3Ey3Yg6Trg) of Blackpool, UK)

Comment: Thanks Richard.  I'm using v3 but I think it is the removing and adding the marker that is the key.  I'll try it tonight.

Comment: I think [Mike Williams](http://stackoverflow.com/users/176492/mike-williams) deserves the credit (assuming the stackoverflow Mike Williams is the same guy who posted this answer on google groups) - I gave him a few random upvotes on your behalf anyway!

Comment: The issues and this solution would indicate that it's a scope issue: `_marker` is local to some function, and the `setTitle` is happening outside that function.

Answer (score 15):

In API v3 it would be:

```
marker.setTitle('new title');
```

Answer (score 0):

For the new version of Google map api you can use **setTitle()** to chang the title of any existing marker

Example

```
marker.setTitle("new title");
```